# How to safely transform list params filter before requesting the server

Tags: javascript, java, spring, reactjs, admin-on-rest

I am looking at admin-on-rest source code to establish the possibilities we have to communicate with our backend.

We use spring-data and querydsl, because of that, we don't have much flexibility on how we can receive these filter params.

They should be `?username=foobar`
Instead of `?filter={ username: 'foobar }`

I am not sure for us if our best option is to fork and work on our side, or if there is a better way to hook the request process and update the request without changing how `changeListParams` and `query` works. (See [List.js#L85](https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest/blob/master/src/mui/list/List.js#L85))

Version: 1.3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the job of a custom [`restClient`](https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/RestClients.html#writing-your-own-rest-client).

Check the params contains a `filter` property and apply any transformations you like to make it compatible with your backend.

Comment: I've already applied that plumbing to my `restClient`. What lead me to the wrong conclusion was my filtering rerendering leading to impossible typing and I assumed it was because of the client url changing.